# Creating a 2D array using values of coordinate points on a grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have a coordinate grid with a few points(masses) sprinkled in the grid. I can create this using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

points = np.array([[0,1],[2,1],[3,5]]) # array containing the coordinates of masses(points) in the form [x,y]

x1, y1 = zip(*points)
```

Now, I can plot using :

```
plt.plot(x1,y1,'.')
```

[image: Plot of points]

Now, say I create a 2D meshgrid using:

```
x = np.linspace(-10,10,10)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

Now, what I want to do is to create a 2D array 'Z',(a map of the masses)that contains masses at the locations that are in the array **points**. When I mean masses, I just mean a scalar at those points. So I could do something like **plt.contourf(X,Y,Z)**. The problem I'm having is that the indices for Z cannot be the same as the coordinates in points. There has to be some sort of conversion which I'm not able to figure out. Another way to look at it is I want:

```
Z[X,Y] = 1
```

I want Z to have 1's at locations which are specified by the array **points**. So the essence of the problem is how do I calculate the X and Y indices such that they correspond to x1, y1 in real coordinates.

For example, if I simply do Z[x1(i),y1(i)] = 1, contourf gives this:
Instead I want the spikes to be at (0,1),(2,1),(3,5).
[image]

Comment: Why not do simply `Z[x[i], y[i]] = 1` ?

Comment: That just makes me have the masses at the pixel values of Z, so basically its own indices. The coordinates of the masses are not pixel values but actual numbers on Cartesian grid.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: I want Z[x1,y1] = 1 but if I actually type that in code, Python assigns 1 to the index values of Z, not to x1 and y1 if I use X and Y as the meshgrids...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a constant function (equal to 1) evaluated on a grid represented by x and y coordinates ? Then just do `Z = np.ones(X.shape))`. You can then use it in `plt.contourf(x, y, Z)`.

Comment: not a constant one, I want it at the coordinate points specified by x1,y1. Picture a smooth plane, with spikes at certain points.

Comment: Oh, I'm starting to see what you want. I'll try and write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To have 1 at the coordinates specified by x1, y1 and zeros everywhere else, I would write it like this:

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 21)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 21)
Z = np.zeros((len(y), len(x)))
for i in range(len(x1)):
    Z[10 + y1[i], 10 + x1[i]] = 1
```

Then you should be able to write `plt.contourf(x, y, Z)`.

Tell me if that gives you the desired result.

Comment: I've tried this method, problem is that it only works if the pixel values are the same as the integer values. As in, 1 pixel corresponds to 1 unit distance in x, so this wouldn't work say if I had x = np.linspace(-50,50,21)

Comment: Then you should make sure that you have integer values in your grid. Or at least that the values inside x1 and y1 are actually points on your grid.

Comment: so the main issue is, say I have a number 0.5 inside x1, then I can't use this method, is there a way to do it for non integer numbers? If I do have a grid containing say [0,0.5,1], I still can't assign the coordinate to the 2nd pixel in an efficient manner...

Comment: You could try having a fine enough resolution on your grid. For example, if you know your points in x1 and y1 are defined with a precision of 0.01, then create your grid with that precision as well. Only problem is that you'll start getting a really big grid for small precision.

Comment: Say for example I want to plot a point with a value 3.3, contained in x1, and my grid has a 0.1 resolution with n = 21, I can't do Z[10+3.3] = 1, since this will give me an error for the index not being an integer. How do I make the code find the index which corresponds to 3.3 in real values and then make it plot the point there?

Comment: You would have to do `Z[10 + 10 * 3.3]`. And instead of 21, you should use 201. In my answer I assumed x1 and y1 would only contain integers between -10 and 10

Comment: but the 10 comes from the fact that 21/2, if I use 201, it'll be 201/2, and then Z[201/2 + 201/2*3.3] = 1, the indices would still be floats...which is a real problem

Comment: I think you're getting confused by the linear transformation. The formula is Z[10 + x1[i],...] because the grid starts at -10 with precision 1. If your grid starts at -10 with precision 0.001, then it would be Z[10 / 0.001 + x1[i] / 0.001,...] = Z[10000 + 1000 * x1[i],...]. And you would declare your grid with `linspace(-10, 10, 20001)`

Comment: you're right! I was getting confused about that, now it makes sense, this works great in a general case! thanks! so basically, if linspace(-n,n,pixels), I would do Z[n/(n*2/pixels-1) + x1[i]/samething,...] yes? Does this n depend simply on the last interval value? what if it was [-5,10]?